# Android 2.1 Bluetooth SPP to LM058 (Serial Cable Replacement) problem

Tags: android, connection, bluetooth, serial-port

Hey I'm relatively new to Android programming (but not programming in general).

The Setup:
HTC Wildfire (running Android 2.1)
LM058 (RS232 Serial Cable Replacement)
LM058 will later on be attached to a MCU but for now it's connected to my laptop (terminal)

The Goal:
To connect Wildfire to LM058 to each other with a 'bidirectional-stream' (like: "Hello from Android", response: "Hey from LM058").

So far:
I've managed to connect the two devices (paired), I can tell by the LEDs on the LM058.

Problem:
I can't seem to send anything from my Wildfire to LM058, and can't write anything back. They are paired and Connected.

Code example:

```
            String message = "Hello message from client to server.";
            byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
            try {
             outStream.write(msgBuffer);

       Log.e(TAG, "App was here!");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ON RESUME: Exception during write.", e);
            }
```

I have previously made a similar connection using a Windows Mobile succesfully, but Android seems to give me some trouble at this point.

If you can help me get passed this small hurdle I would be very gratefull!

Could it have anything to do with BaudRate, because when a link is established (paired and Connected) it should replace the two devices (as a simple RS232 cable), so my Terminal on the PC should be set to a certain BaudRate (since I can't seem to find Baud Rate in Android). But still I can't see anything, if Baudrate was wrong then I would be able to see something (even though it might be rubbish) or?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't Baudrate for Bluetooth connection, only you have to configure the baudrate between your BT-RS232 device and your computer...

For the BluetoothConnection you could see the next example:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

or this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html